# Retrieving from link from sharepoint into mail

Tags: 2010, infopath

I am creating an Infopath form to submit into a sharepoint library.
I am asked to create a button that would automatically send an email to the task responsible with a link to the editable form.

The sending mail part is no problem but i cannot figure out how to get the link from the sharepoint specific item into this mail.

Hope some can help me.

[image: I need to get this link in the mail sent to the task responsible]

Answer (score 0):

Just use the ID of the item you are getting and build your URL correctly.  If you are getting the item from a different list, you will have to pass the ID to the list you are building your email off of.  Use xPath and managed code if you want the button on the InfoPath form.  Then just build your URL correctly  Example:   href="http://mySharePoint/Lists/My%20Custom%20List/EditForm.aspx?ID={ID_Variable}"

Or you can get fancy and create your own custom ribbon button to run a workflow and do the same thing.  A little CSOM to capture getSelectedItems and you can do many at once.

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
```

I hope this helps.  Good Luck!